# SQL condition base on number of associations

Tags: mysql, sql, associations, conditional-statements

I'm trying to run a query on my user database and I'm running into a bit of trouble. I want to grab the number of associated rows and base a condition off of that. I'll let my scenario explain:

Users can have_many videos in my app. In my case, I want to return all users who don't have videos. There are a few more conditions as well, but this is the one where I'm having trouble. My query ideally would be something like (kinda sudo-code):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM users 
JOIN videos ON users.id=videos.user_id
WHERE
  users.some_attribute = 1
  OR
  (users.last_login >= '03/18/2012' AND COUNT(videos) > 0)
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Thanks!!
 - Jeff

Comment: To get "all users who don't have videos" you need `LEFT OUTER JOIN`  and then `IS NULL` in your `WHERE` condition.

Comment: What SQL Flavor (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) are you using?  What is the **data type** of `users.last_login`?

Comment: It's mysql, last_login is datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the Having statement in SQL:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM users 
JOIN videos ON users.id=videos.user_id
WHERE  users.some_attribute = 1   OR   users.last_login >= '03/18/2012'
HAVING COUNT(videos.<some_column>) > 0)
```

Adding EDIT in response to below comment:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM users 
WHERE  users.some_attribute = 1   
UNION 
SELECT count(*) FROM users 
JOIN videos ON users.id=videos.user_id
WHERE  users.last_login >= '03/18/2012'
HAVING COUNT(videos.<some_column>) > 0)
```

Comment: This was the clearest answer that worked quickly (my db has 1.8 million user rows). However, I don't think this is exact, since the having clause is outside of the conditions (I want to find records with some_attribute=1 OR (last_login >= 03/18/2012 AND having count(videos.id)).

Comment: @Jeff....glad it helped. In order to accomplish you OR I think you'll need to UNION with two queries. See new query

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GROUP BY with a HAVING attribute

```
SELECT usercolumns, count(videos.user_id) 
FROM users 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN videos ON users.id=videos.user_id
WHERE users.some_attribute = 1
GROUP BY usercolumns HAVING users.last_login >= '03/18/2012' AND COUNT(videos.user_id) > 0
```

If you really want all the columns you can also use a subQuery

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT userscolumns, count(videos.user_id) 
    FROM users 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN videos ON users.id=videos.user_id
    WHERE users.some_attribute = 1
    GROUP BY userscolumns
) A
WHERE users.last_login >= '03/18/2012' 
AND COUNT(videos.user_id) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Not Exists would work best

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM users 
WHERE
users.some_attribute = 1
OR
(users.last_login >= '03/18/2012' 
and not exists 
 (
 select count(videos.videofield) 
 from videos 
 where users.id=videos.user_id
 )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.user FROM users u
LEFT JOIN videos v ON u.id=v_id
WHERE v_id IS NULL AND 
  (users.some_attribute = 1
  OR
  users.last_login >= STR_TO_DATE('03/18/2012', '%m/%d/%Y'))
```